# How to show customer dropdown attribute as radio button in registration page - Magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, magento2.3, magento2.4

I have created a customer drop-down attribute from admin, in the registration page i need to show it as a radio button, how can achieve this. is it possible to show its as radio button, if not is there any alternative option?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To display a customer dropdown attribute as a radio button on the registration page in Magento 2, you'll need to create a custom module and perform some customization.

Here's a step-by-step guide to achieve this:

**1. Create a Custom Module:** Create a custom module in the app/code directory of your Magento installation. Let's call it **Vendor_CustomerAttribute**.

**2. Define the Customer Attribute:**
In your custom module, define the customer attribute. Create the necessary files to set up the attribute:

**app/code/Vendor/CustomerAttribute/Setup/InstallData.php
app/code/Vendor/CustomerAttribute/Setup/UpgradeData.php**

In these files, use Magento's setup scripts to add the customer attribute of the dropdown type.
you can take reference from below links :

**[How to create customer custom attribute for radio buttons, checkbox in magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/256448/how-to-create-customer-custom-attribute-for-radio-buttons-checkbox-in-magento-2)**

**3. Modify the Registration Form:**
Create a custom layout XML file in your module to modify the registration form layout. This can be done in a file like **app/code/Vendor/CustomerAttribute/view/frontend/layout/customer_account_create.xml.**

```
   <?xml version="1.0"?>
   <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
       <body>
           <referenceBlock name="customer_form_register">
               <action method="setTemplate">
                   <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Vendor_CustomerAttribute::form/register.phtml</argument>
               </action>
           </referenceBlock>
       </body>
   </page>
```

**4. Create the Template File:**
Create a custom template file for the registration form in your module: **app/code/Vendor/CustomerAttribute/view/frontend/templates/form/register.phtml**.

Inside this template, you can customize the rendering of your custom attribute as radio buttons. Here's an example:

```
   <?php /* @var $block \Magento\Customer\Block\Form\Register */ ?>
   <?php $_customAttribute = $block->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Customer\Block\Widget\Gender'); ?>

   <div class="field gender required">
       <label for="gender" class="label"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Gender')) ?></span></label>
       <div class="control">
           <?= $_customAttribute->setShowAsRadio(true)->toHtml(); ?>
       </div>
   </div>
```

In this example, we're assuming that the customer attribute code is **"gender"**. You should replace it with your actual attribute code.

**5. Clear Cache:**
After making these changes, clear the cache and test the registration form.